# dax if column is null or blank how can I set my as result previous column

Tags: dax, tabular

currently my dax formula is =pathitem([hierarchy path]), 3) for column3 but I want to add formula that if column is blank or null get value from column2. How can I write dax formula for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
=
IF (
    ISBLANK ( PATHITEM ( [Hierarchy Path], 3 ) ),
    [Column3],
    PATHITEM ( [Hierarchy Path], 3 )
)
```

Column3 would have to be Data Type Text.

Comment: Thanks again Rory, but I found out calling previous column was not the solution :(